# Ambiguous occurrence ‘foldMap’

Tags: haskell, foldable

I am implementing Foldable for the following data structure:

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving Show
```

When I implement fold and foldMap:

```
instance Foldable Tree where 

--fold :: Monoid a => Tree a -> a
fold (Leaf x) = x
fold (Node l r) = fold l `mappend` fold r

--foldMap :: Monoid b => (a -> b) -> Tree a -> b 
foldMap f (Leaf x) = f x
foldMap f (Node l r) = foldMap f l `mappend` foldMap f r
```

I will get the following error:

```
    Ambiguous occurrence ‘foldMap’
    It could refer to either ‘Main.foldMap’,
                             defined at Chapterh14.hs:57:1
                          or ‘Prelude.foldMap’,
                             imported from ‘Prelude’ at Chapterh14.hs:1:1
                             (and originally defined in ‘Data.Foldable’)

Chapterh14.hs:58:46:
    Ambiguous occurrence ‘foldMap’
    It could refer to either ‘Main.foldMap’,
                             defined at Chapterh14.hs:57:1
                          or ‘Prelude.foldMap’,
                             imported from ‘Prelude’ at Chapterh14.hs:1:1
                             (and originally defined in ‘Data.Foldable’)

Chapterh14.hs:71:13:
    Ambiguous occurrence ‘foldMap’
    It could refer to either ‘Main.foldMap’,
                             defined at Chapterh14.hs:57:1
                          or ‘Prelude.foldMap’,
                             imported from ‘Prelude’ at Chapterh14.hs:1:1
                             (and originally defined in ‘Data.Foldable’)
```

When I remove the definition of foldMap I will get the following warning:

```
    No explicit implementation for
      either ‘foldMap’ or ‘foldr’
    In the instance declaration for ‘Foldable Tree’
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
```

When I implement the function I will get the error that it is already there, but when I do not implement the function I will get a warning that the function is missing? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to indent your `fold` and `foldMap` declarations so they're part of the `instance`.

```
instance Foldable Tree where
    --fold :: Monoid a => Tree a -> a
    fold (Leaf x) = x
    fold (Node l r) = fold l `mappend` fold r

    --foldMap :: Monoid b => (a -> b) -> Tree a -> b
    foldMap f (Leaf x) = f x
    foldMap f (Node l r) = foldMap f l `mappend` foldMap f r
```

When you had them un-indented, the machine saw an empty `instance` declaration and two unrelated top-level functions called `fold` and `foldMap`. The empty instance was the source of the "No explicit implementation" error (why that's a warning and not an error I don't know). The "ambiguous occurrence" error was because the compiler couldn't tell whether the recursive calls to `foldMap` were referring to the implicitly imported `Prelude.foldMap` or to the `Main.foldMap` in your code.

Comment: "why that's a warning and not an error I don't know" -- good point. Maybe it's because every method has a default definition? Usually, through, such defaults are mutually recursive, and will simply diverge unless the user defines some method. E.g. `Eq` has both  `==,/=` defaulted, but requires at least one of those to be defined to work properly.

Comment: @chi It looks like it's always a warning, even when the missing functions don't have a default implementation. `instance Functor Foo where {}` produces a warning only. I'm sure there must be a good reason for it...

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson I'm not sure whether you'd call it a "good" reason, but occasionally you want to use an ill-thought-out class (`Num`, I'm looking at you...) even though some of the methods don't make complete sense for your type. Having a default default implementation (that was not a typo -- it is a default implementation written for you by the compiler) that calls `error` is kind of convenient in that situation.

Comment: @DanielWagner But then again, if you decide you want to call `error` then doing so explicitly is not so painful

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Indeed. I wouldn't upgrade my judgment above "kind of convenient". =)